# The heat equation for complex time

Tags: differential-operators, heat-equation, ricci-flow

Let $\Delta$ be a Laplacian or an elliptic operator over a manifold, can the heat equation be defined for complex time? Can we define:
$$e^{-z \Delta}$$
for $Re(z)>0$ ?
Also can the Ricci flow be defined for complex time?

Comment: This can be done and the keyword is "analytic semigroup" but usually only when $z$ is confined in an angle strictly contained in the right half plane. If the operator is self-adjoint, via the spectral theory one can do the same in the whole right half plane (but only in $L^2$) and the equation changes its nature along vertical lines.

Comment: Does the Schrödinger equation have an analytic semigroup?

Comment: The Laplacian generates an analytic semigroup, not the Schroedinger operator.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ in real time corresponds to heat equation, while in imaginary time it corresponds to the Schrödinger equation. Complex time does not have a physics realization, but it has been used as a device to study the blow-up of solutions in the presence of quadratic nonlinearities ($u_t=u_{xx}+u^2$), see [Complex time blow-up of the nonlinear heat equation.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.10707)

Comment: You say that the complex time has no physics realization, but I have heard of a physics theory of the complex time with a particule, the transion.

Comment: hmm, never heard of a "transion" ...